# Mac Pro 5,1 Mid 2010 RAM Slots

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I have just bought 2x16GB ram. I have 4 slots with 8gb in each. I will fit the new 2x16 in slots 1 + 2 (4 slots total). Is that correct?

Comment: In the About This Mac > Memory tab, see the link to "Memory Upgrade Instructions".

Comment: @GEdgar - please don't put answers in comments, especially when they have already been addressed in actual answers. Answers in comments say to the world, "I'm too important to be subject to the same voting rules as anyone else. My answer deserves to be seen first."

Comment: BTW, the Apple instructions linked from that Memory tab are wrong. After a firmware update at maybe High Sierra, these will take 16GB sticks, in pairs for a 128GB max. [They will also take sticks in triple-channel for a faster 96GB max]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 2009 4,1 & 2010/12 5,1 Mac Pro single Xeons use RAM in adjacent pairs [unlike the old 2008 3,1 which looks like a knitting pattern;)

[image]

The dual processor Macs use a slightly more complex pattern, involving both banks, but the single cores are easy.

[image]

The info is linked directly from About this Mac > Memory > Memory Upgrade instructions, to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205043

If you do anything it doesn't like it will spring a warning dialog [I don't have an image] otherwise you'll see everything looks fine in that same memory tab…

[image]

BTW, ignore the note that you can only get 32GB [single CPU] or 64GB [dual CPU] as the 16GB chips were never certified by Apple, but have long been proven to work just fine, so long as you're running [iirc] El Capitan. [On the dual CPU Macs, there was one point - maybe around El Capitan -  where you could run 64GB in 8s, but only 96GB in 16s, running triple channel. This was fixed in a firmware update by High Sierra or Mojave. I'm not sure how that affected the single CPU Macs.]

Comment: I think the question was what to do if you have two 8GB and two 16GB simms.

Comment: @GEdgar - yes, which I answered in the opening sentence.